# create a VS2013 project with cuda options via cmake

Tags: cuda, cmake, project-settings

I'm working with a CUDA project. I see there're options like `CUDA C/C++` and `CUDA Linker` when the project is created using CUDA project wizard.

I wonder if it's possible to create such project with cmake?

The command

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" ..
```

just creates a normal c++ project that has no CUDA option.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding you are trying to use CMake in a way it is not designed to. You should adjust all project properties using FindCUDA and then won't need to access any in Visual Studio.

From [this question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856929/configuring-cmake-to-setup-cuda-on-windows?rq=1) I gather that CMake is not able to create these options.